# Is it posible send sms by SMPP protocol from sql server?

Tags: sql-server, smpp

I want to send many sms that they are exit in a sql server table.
Already I sending theme by c# and using SMPP.
But I want to send theme directly from sql server for example using a sp or a function.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything is on Windows platform,

- Implement a SMS API using your C# and SMPP
- Enable xp_cmdshell by executing sp_configure
- Install cURL
- Execute curl command from your query

  ```
  DECLARE @Command varchar(1024) = 'curl http://mydotNetAPI/sms -d number=959401591181 -d "message=hello from sql server"'
  EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
  ```

> Note: http://mydotNetAPI/sms should be your C# API to relay SMS message.
>
> Or you shall try http://textbelt.com/text which is a free outgoing SMS API.

for e.g.

```
$ curl -X POST http://textbelt.com/text \
   -d number=5551234567 \
   -d "message=I sent this message for free with textbelt.com"
```

Ref: https://github.com/typpo/textbelt